# How to concatenate image names with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and trying to make a chess game but i have some trouble concatenating imagenames in a way that tkinter understands. The idea here is that the ChessBoard array will be updated every move and then the board will be redrawn. ("--.png" is not the problem)

```
from tkinter import *
board = Tk()

ChessBoard = [
    ["bR","bK","bB","bQ","bK","bB","bK","bR"],
    ["bP","bP","bP","bP","bP","bP","bP","bP"],
    ["--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--"],
    ["--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--"],
    ["--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--"],
    ["--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--"],
    ["wP","wP","wP","wP","wP","wP","wP","wP"],
    ["wR","wK","wB","wQ","wK","wB","wK","wR"],
    
]


for i in range(len(ChessBoard)):
    for j in range(len(ChessBoard[i])):
        if (i % 2 == 0 and j % 2 == 0 or i % 2 != 0 and j % 2 != 0):
            Button(board,bg="#FFF5DA",width=80, height=80, image= PhotoImage(file = r"images/" + 
ChessBoard[i][j] + ".png")).grid(row=i,column=j)
        else:
            Button(board,bg="#202020",width=80, height=80, image= PhotoImage(file = r"images/" + 
ChessBoard[i][j] + ".png")).grid(row=i,column=j)


board.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is your *trouble* actually?

Comment: Your images will disappear before they're ever visible, since you're not saving a reference to each one of them.

Comment: i can't directly pass PhotoImage as argument in button image.  image= PhotoImage(file = r"images/" + 
ChessBoard[i][j] + ".png"))